# ReactJS fails to update

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm copying an event handler in the root component which performs some calculations and then updates state. However, state is not updated when the function is first triggered. On subsequent triggers, state is updated. Here is the function:

```
startSession ( interval = 60000 )  {
  console.log('start session')
  let {timeToEnd, isActive, displayTimer, displayTimerSeconds } = this.state;
  isActive = true;
  timeToEnd = ( displayTimer * 60 * 1000 ) + ( displayTimerSeconds * 10000 ) + Date.now();
  this.setState({
    isActive, timeToEnd
  })
  this.sessionInterval()
}
```

I've checked the usual suspects (scoping, etc) and can't find a culprit. The calculations in the function are performed but nothing happens with `this.setState()`.

Here is the toolkit:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^5.8.34",
  "babel-loader": "^5.3.3",
  "react": "^0.14.3",
  "webpack": "^1.12.9"
},
"dependencies": {
  "react-dom": "^0.14.3"
}
```

Comment: Where you call the `startSession ` the first time?

Comment: How are you verifying "state is not updated when the function is first triggered" ?